# Ingesting data into mosquitto broker with QoS=1

Tags: mqtt, iot, mosquitto, paho

I am trying to ingest data into mosquitto docker image on my local machine with QoS=1. However I can see that the subscriber is getting stuck at record count = 20.
For my demo application I am ingesting 500 records every second for a duration of 20 seconds. I can see that the subscriber behaviour is constant.

Here is the data generator code.

Any help to resolve this is highly appreciated.

Publisher code :

```
import paho.mqtt.client as paho 
from paho import mqtt
from random import randrange, uniform
import time
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing import Process
from os import getpid
import random
import datetime


def task():
    pid = getpid()
    machine_name =  str(pid)
    topic_name = "TEMP"

  
    for i in range(20) :

        mqttBroker ="localhost" 
        client = paho.Client("Temperature_Inside")
        client.connect(mqttBroker,1883) 

        for _ in range(500):
            sensor_reading = str(random.uniform(10, 12))
            ingest_time = str(datetime.datetime.now())
            sensor_payload = "{ 'Topic_Name': \'" + topic_name + "\', 'Msg_Id': \'" + str(i)+ '-'+ str(_) + "\', 'Ingestion_Time': \'" + ingest_time + "\', 'Machine_Name': \'" + machine_name + "\','Reading': \'"+ sensor_reading +"\' }"
            print(sensor_payload)
            client.publish(topic_name,sensor_payload,qos=1)
            
        sleep(1)



# entry point
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    n=1
    for i in range(n):
        process = Process(target=task)
        process.start()
```

Subscriber code :

```
import paho.mqtt.client as paho 
from paho import mqtt
import time

def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    print("received message: " ,str(message.payload.decode("utf-8")))
    with open('files_sub/data_recv.txt','a+') as f:
         f.write("Message received: "  + str(message.payload) + "\n")

mqttBroker ="localhost"
client = paho.Client("Smartphone")
client.connect(mqttBroker,1883) 


client.loop_start()

client.subscribe("#",qos=1)
client.on_message=on_message 

time.sleep(300)
client.loop_stop()
```

Here is sample output from the subscriber:

```
received message:  { 'Topic_Name': 'TEMP_1', 'Msg_Id': '0-0', 'Ingestion_Time': '2023-04-14 20:28:45.272753', 'Machine_Name': '89420','Reading': '11.245454110882422' }
received message:  { 'Topic_Name': 'TEMP_1', 'Msg_Id': '0-1', 'Ingestion_Time': '2023-04-14 20:28:45.272827', 'Machine_Name': '89420','Reading': '10.081152605834397' }
received message:  { 'Topic_Name': 'TEMP_1', 'Msg_Id': '0-2', 'Ingestion_Time': '2023-04-14 20:28:45.272855', 'Machine_Name': '89420','Reading': '11.220300354309748' }
received message:  { 'Topic_Name': 'TEMP_1', 'Msg_Id': '0-3', 'Ingestion_Time': '2023-04-14 20:28:45.272876', 'Machine_Name': '89420','Reading': '11.518400833393375' }
received message:  { 'Topic_Name': 'TEMP_1', 'Msg_Id': '0-4', 'Ingestion_Time': '2023-04-14 20:28:45.272892', 'Machine_Name': '89420','Reading': '10.812436901960156' }
received message:  { 'Topic_Name': 'TEMP_1', 'Msg_Id': '0-5', 'Ingestion_Time': '2023-04-14 20:28:45.272909', 'Machine_Name': '89420','Reading': '10.452335463113961' }
received message:  { 'Topic_Name': 'TEMP_1', 'Msg_Id': '0-6', 'Ingestion_Time': '2023-04-14 20:28:45.272927', 'Machine_Name': '89420','Reading': '11.169666283225068' }
received message:  { 'Topic_Name': 'TEMP_1', 'Msg_Id': '0-7', 'Ingestion_Time': '2023-04-14 20:28:45.272944', 'Machine_Name': '89420','Reading': '10.384115735731186' }
received message:  { 'Topic_Name': 'TEMP_1', 'Msg_Id': '0-8', 'Ingestion_Time': '2023-04-14 20:28:45.272962', 'Machine_Name': '89420','Reading': '10.713527094563638' }
received message:  { 'Topic_Name': 'TEMP_1', 'Msg_Id': '0-9', 'Ingestion_Time': '2023-04-14 20:28:45.272982', 'Machine_Name': '89420','Reading': '10.598582170350706' }
received message:  { 'Topic_Name': 'TEMP_1', 'Msg_Id': '0-10', 'Ingestion_Time': '2023-04-14 20:28:45.273001', 'Machine_Name': '89420','Reading': '11.361539934144364' }
received message:  { 'Topic_Name': 'TEMP_1', 'Msg_Id': '0-11', 'Ingestion_Time': '2023-04-14 20:28:45.273021', 'Machine_Name': '89420','Reading': '11.663632627831358' }
received message:  { 'Topic_Name': 'TEMP_1', 'Msg_Id': '0-12', 'Ingestion_Time': '2023-04-14 20:28:45.273044', 'Machine_Name': '89420','Reading': '10.65691717505538' }
received message:  { 'Topic_Name': 'TEMP_1', 'Msg_Id': '0-13', 'Ingestion_Time': '2023-04-14 20:28:45.273068', 'Machine_Name': '89420','Reading': '10.904640065408845' }
received message:  { 'Topic_Name': 'TEMP_1', 'Msg_Id': '0-14', 'Ingestion_Time': '2023-04-14 20:28:45.273089', 'Machine_Name': '89420','Reading': '11.203352658202002' }
received message:  { 'Topic_Name': 'TEMP_1', 'Msg_Id': '0-15', 'Ingestion_Time': '2023-04-14 20:28:45.273104', 'Machine_Name': '89420','Reading': '10.520332978869524' }
received message:  { 'Topic_Name': 'TEMP_1', 'Msg_Id': '0-16', 'Ingestion_Time': '2023-04-14 20:28:45.273122', 'Machine_Name': '89420','Reading': '10.897221818925265' }
received message:  { 'Topic_Name': 'TEMP_1', 'Msg_Id': '0-17', 'Ingestion_Time': '2023-04-14 20:28:45.273137', 'Machine_Name': '89420','Reading': '10.958659355435096' }
received message:  { 'Topic_Name': 'TEMP_1', 'Msg_Id': '0-18', 'Ingestion_Time': '2023-04-14 20:28:45.273154', 'Machine_Name': '89420','Reading': '10.143412660261575' }
received message:  { 'Topic_Name': 'TEMP_1', 'Msg_Id': '0-19', 'Ingestion_Time': '2023-04-14 20:28:45.273172', 'Machine_Name': '89420','Reading': '11.820377674321305' }
received message:  { 'Topic_Name': 'TEMP_1', 'Msg_Id': '1-0', 'Ingestion_Time': '2023-04-14 20:28:46.289744', 'Machine_Name': '89420','Reading': '11.29543750293708' }
received message:  { 'Topic_Name': 'TEMP_1', 'Msg_Id': '1-1', 'Ingestion_Time': '2023-04-14 20:28:46.290117', 'Machine_Name': '89420','Reading': '10.643004903851944' }
received message:  { 'Topic_Name': 'TEMP_1', 'Msg_Id': '1-2', 'Ingestion_Time': '2023-04-14 20:28:46.290295', 'Machine_Name': '89420','Reading': '10.458158806515144' }
received message:  { 'Topic_Name': 'TEMP_1', 'Msg_Id': '1-3', 'Ingestion_Time': '2023-04-14 20:28:46.290402', 'Machine_Name': '89420','Reading': '10.978263816038918' }
received message:  { 'Topic_Name': 'TEMP_1', 'Msg_Id': '1-4', 'Ingestion_Time': '2023-04-14 20:28:46.291308', 'Machine_Name': '89420','Reading': '10.391060321348153' }
received message:  { 'Topic_Name': 'TEMP_1', 'Msg_Id': '1-5', 'Ingestion_Time': '2023-04-14 20:28:46.291526', 'Machine_Name': '89420','Reading': '11.831071429545204' }
received message:  { 'Topic_Name': 'TEMP_1', 'Msg_Id': '1-6', 'Ingestion_Time': '2023-04-14 20:28:46.291618', 'Machine_Name': '89420','Reading': '10.905535280792117' }
received message:  { 'Topic_Name': 'TEMP_1', 'Msg_Id': '1-7', 'Ingestion_Time': '2023-04-14 20:28:46.291682', 'Machine_Name': '89420','Reading': '10.8712642203881' }
received message:  { 'Topic_Name': 'TEMP_1', 'Msg_Id': '1-8', 'Ingestion_Time': '2023-04-14 20:28:46.291735', 'Machine_Name': '89420','Reading': '10.736403240547105' }
received message:  { 'Topic_Name': 'TEMP_1', 'Msg_Id': '1-9', 'Ingestion_Time': '2023-04-14 20:28:46.291782', 'Machine_Name': '89420','Reading': '10.668622663674302' }
received message:  { 'Topic_Name': 'TEMP_1', 'Msg_Id': '1-10', 'Ingestion_Time': '2023-04-14 20:28:46.291842', 'Machine_Name': '89420','Reading': '10.008705910490459' }
received message:  { 'Topic_Name': 'TEMP_1', 'Msg_Id': '1-11', 'Ingestion_Time': '2023-04-14 20:28:46.291904', 'Machine_Name': '89420','Reading': '11.52470881947238' }
received message:  { 'Topic_Name': 'TEMP_1', 'Msg_Id': '1-12', 'Ingestion_Time': '2023-04-14 20:28:46.291962', 'Machine_Name': '89420','Reading': '11.478288851483171' }
received message:  { 'Topic_Name': 'TEMP_1', 'Msg_Id': '1-13', 'Ingestion_Time': '2023-04-14 20:28:46.292018', 'Machine_Name': '89420','Reading': '11.43596822016599' }
received message:  { 'Topic_Name': 'TEMP_1', 'Msg_Id': '1-14', 'Ingestion_Time': '2023-04-14 20:28:46.292073', 'Machine_Name': '89420','Reading': '10.07599401587021' }
received message:  { 'Topic_Name': 'TEMP_1', 'Msg_Id': '1-15', 'Ingestion_Time': '2023-04-14 20:28:46.292128', 'Machine_Name': '89420','Reading': '11.429841926223641' }
received message:  { 'Topic_Name': 'TEMP_1', 'Msg_Id': '1-16', 'Ingestion_Time': '2023-04-14 20:28:46.292184', 'Machine_Name': '89420','Reading': '11.975174671732594' }
received message:  { 'Topic_Name': 'TEMP_1', 'Msg_Id': '1-17', 'Ingestion_Time': '2023-04-14 20:28:46.292232', 'Machine_Name': '89420','Reading': '10.09898131578267' }
received message:  { 'Topic_Name': 'TEMP_1', 'Msg_Id': '1-18', 'Ingestion_Time': '2023-04-14 20:28:46.292274', 'Machine_Name': '89420','Reading': '10.582514581651441' }
received message:  { 'Topic_Name': 'TEMP_1', 'Msg_Id': '1-19', 'Ingestion_Time': '2023-04-14 20:28:46.292317', 'Machine_Name': '89420','Reading': '10.532774491896046' }
```

Comment: Hi @ritabrata saha, please edit the question to include the complete code for the publisher - a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It's missing some critical parts and it's difficult to give accurate advice without seeing the whole thing.

Comment: @romkey I have shared the complete publisher code. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Rtiabata Saha,

The PAHO Python MQTT client implements a network loop to handle network traffic and account for the delivery of messages per QoS.  You must be hitting a buffer limit on how many messages you can send without invoking the network loop, or the # of QoS 1 messages that you can send without the client processing the acknowledgement.

You have options on how to manage the "network loop". [Refer: https://pypi.org/project/paho-mqtt/#network-loop](https://pypi.org/project/paho-mqtt/#network-loop).  It looks like the simplest approach to get you started would be to use loop_start() after your connect to spawn a background thread to handle the network loop for you asynchronously.  From the reference:

```
mqttc.connect("mqtt.eclipseprojects.io")
mqttc.loop_start()

while True:
    temperature = sensor.blocking_read()
    mqttc.publish("paho/temperature", temperature)
```